# Error while reading textfile to Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am running basic pyspark program as below in PySpark (1.6.0) but I am getting error. As per PySpark documentation https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/sql-programming-guide.html, the syntax seems to be correct but still not sure why it saying that 'SQLContext' object has no attribute 'textFile'

```
from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

    if __name__ == '__main__':
            conf = SparkConf().setAppName('TestingDF')
            sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
            sqlc = SQLContext(sc)
            lines = sqlc.textFile('/user/cloudera/practice4/question3/customers').map(lambda x: x.split(','))
```

I am getting below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'SQLContext' object has no attribute 'textFile'
```

'/user/cloudera/practice4/question3/customers' is basically sql table that I imported to HDFS from mysql via sqoop command

Python version is 2.6.6 (Basically I am testing all this on cloudera Quickstart VM 5.13)

Comment: You shoud be using `sc.textFile(path)` instead

Comment: You should actually be using `sqlc.table("table_name")` if its a Hive table